# Resizing dynamically allocated pointer array to class

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

How would you resize an array without using vectors?
The array I want to resize is a pointer to a class

```
class A
{
    private:
    B * b;
    int numOfItems;
    int maxNumOfItems;

    public:
    A();
    ~A();
    resizeMX();
};


A::A()
{
     numOfItems = 0;
     maxNumOfItems = 20;
     b = new B[maxNumOfItems];
     for(int i=0;i<maxNumOfItems ;i++)
     {
         b[i] = 0;
     }
}

A::~A()
{
    for(int i=0;i<numOfItems;i++)
     {
         delete [] b;
     }
}

void A::resizeMX(const B & obj)
{
     bool value=false;
     if(numOfItems<=maxNumOfItems && value == false)
     {
        //assign values to *b in for loop
     }
     else
     {
       //resize index of *b
```

I know that we are supposed to dynamically allocate new memory. Something like this?

```
       ++maxNumOfItems; 
        b=new B[maxNumOfItems];
        //keep previous assigned values and add new values at the end
        for(int j=numOfItems;j<maxNumOfItems;j++)
        {
            //assign values to b[j]
        }
     }  
        numOfItems++;
}
```

assume that I did overload the = operator

Comment: You're `~A()` should only call the delete once.  `delete [] b;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot resize array, you can only allocate new one (with a bigger size) and copy old array's contents. If you don't want to use std::vector (for some reason) here is the code to it:

```
int size = 10;
int* arr = new int[size];

void resize() {
    size_t newSize = size * 2;
    int* newArr = new int[newSize];

    memcpy( newArr, arr, size * sizeof(int) );

    size = newSize;
    delete [] arr;
    arr = newArr;
}
```

Comment: Using `memcpy` for C++ objects is usually not a good idea. Instead use e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or loop manually and move the objects.

Comment: well it never did anything wrong for me though. I guess its up to preference and experience. I'll still look into std::copy, thanks :) @JoachimPileborg

Comment: For a basic type like `int`, `memcpy()` works fine.  For a class type, as requested by the OP, it (often) gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: What's the advantage of using `memcpy` over `realloc`?

Answer (score 0):

When you do your reallocation `b = new B[...]` you lose the original pointer, and therefore all previous objects.

Instead you need to use a temporary variable for the new memory, and [copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (or move) from the old `b` to the new memory. Then you *delete* the old memory and reassign the pointer,

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, an array is not a pointer.   A pointer can contain the address of a first element of an array, which may or may not be dynamically allocated.

Anyway, assuming you have a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of `B`

```
pointer = new B[size];   //  assume size > 0

  //  optionally do something with the elements of pointer other than resizing
```

then, to resize it is necessary to dynamically allocate a new array

```
B *new_pointer = new B[newsize];    // assume size < newsize
```

then copy elements to the new array

```
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
      new_pointer[i] = pointer[i];     // relies on B's assignment operator
```

and then release the old dynamically allocated array

```
delete [] pointer;
```

and, lastly, reassign `pointer` to point at the newly allocated array.

```
pointer = new_pointer;
```

A standard container is preferable, since it manages all the allocations and reallocations as needed.